# What's the percent of mango trees?

Tags: percentages

I know this is simple stuff compare to the questions I've seen on this site but please be nice. :) Would be great if anyone could show me how to solve the problem below.

Question:

On a piece of land, 3/8 of the trees are lemon trees. Of the other trees are 8/15 orange trees and 2/5 palm trees. The rest of the trees are mango trees. What's the percent of mango trees? (Answer: 4.2%).

Answer (score 1):

Lemon trees: $\dfrac{3}{8}$

Other trees: $1-\dfrac{3}{8}=\dfrac{5}{8}$

Orange trees: $\dfrac{5}{8}\cdot\dfrac{8}{15}=\dfrac{1}{3}$

Palm trees: $\dfrac{5}{8}\cdot\dfrac{2}{5}=\dfrac{1}{4}$

Mango trees: $1-\left(\dfrac{3}{8}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)=\dfrac{1}{24}$

Comment: I'm sorry but math is like kryptonite to me, how do you get the 1 (on other trees)?

Comment: @Lattja: When you work with percentage, you use $100\%$ in order to denote the total amount, right? Do you understand why? The reason is, that $1$ percent of the amount is equivalent $\frac{1}{100}$ of the amount. So when you work with percentage, you use $100\%$ in order to denote the total amount, and when you work with fractions, you use $1$ in order to denote the total amount. Got it?

Comment: Yes, I get that, total amount, 100% and 1. The rest, it's like, I get it, but I don't get it. Well, I've been staring at math all day; maybe I'll understand it tomorrow and laugh at all of this.